# How can I check the type of an object when adding objects to a Collection<T>?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a question about adding an object to a `Collection<T>` from an inherited class.

Here is some example base class code:

```
public virtual Collection<CustomProperty> customProperties
{
    get
    {
        return _customProperties;
    }
    set
    {
        _customProperties = value;
    }
}
```

Here is some example inherited class code:

```
public override Collection<CustomProperty> customProperties
{
    get
    {
        return base.customProperties;
    }
    set
    {
        base.customProperties = value;
    }
}
```

In the above code, when adding objects that inherit from `CustomProperty`, how is the best way to check if the object is of a certain type, and then call a function if the object is of the certain type?

I can write a function that inherits from `Collection<CustomProperty>` and override the `protected virtual void InsertItem(int index, T item)` function, but would like to know if there is another way.

Comment: Are you saying that the derived class that contains `customProperties` is meant to deal with a derived class of `CustomProperty` too, but because of the inheritance you're seemingly stuck with using `CustomProperty` when you really want something like `SpecialCustomProperty`?

Answer (score 1):

`Collection<T>` is an extensible wrapper around `List<T>`. Inheriting from it and overriding `InsertItem` is the exact way to control that sort of thing.

Is there a reason you need another way?

Here is a little helper i have used in my toolkit many times.

```
class FilteringCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, bool> Filter;
    FilteringCollection(Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        Filter = filter;
    }

    protected override InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if(Filter(item))
             base.InsertItem(index, item);
        else
           ;//either ignore or throw an exception here
    }
}

//Or perhaps
class TypeSensitiveCollection<T, TSpecial> : Collection<T>
    where TSpecial : T
{
    public event EventHandler<TSpecial> SpecialMemberAdded;

    TypeSensitiveCollection()
    {

    }

    protected override InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if(item is TSpecial)
        {
             if(SpecialMemberAdded != null)
                 SpecialMemberAdded(this, item as TSpecial)
        }
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put more details.

Comment: I can add more detail, what would you like me to expand on?

Comment: Well, your answer makes sense now. +1. Please put code the next time in your original answer instead of editing it afterwards.

Comment: It was my first answer, i'll be sure to next time!